# Prove inequality with $a;b;c \in R$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a;b;c \in  \mathbb{R} $ such that $a+b+c=0$
Prove that: $P=\dfrac{a-1}{a^2+8}+\dfrac{b-1}{b^2+8}+\dfrac{c-1}{c^2+8} \geq -\dfrac{3}{8}$

I tried to do this:
$\dfrac{8a-8}{a^2+8}+2+\dfrac{8b-8}{b^2+8}+2+\dfrac{8c-8}{c^2+8}+2 \geq 3$

$\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{(a+2)^2}{a^2+8}+\dfrac{(b+2)^2}{b^2+8}+\dfrac{(c+2)^2}{c^2+8} \geq \dfrac{3}{2}$

Then WLOG $c=max\{a;b;c\} \Rightarrow c \geq 0$

I hope I can prove: $\dfrac{(a+2)^2}{a^2+8}+\dfrac{(b+2)^2}{b^2+8} \geq f(c)$

So I only need to find minimum of $f(c)+\dfrac{(c+2)^2}{c^2+8}$

But I can't find $f(c)$, I stuck here.

Comment: With $R$ you refer to $\mathbb{R}$ ? or $R$ is in arbitrary Ring

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is very good and we will use that :)

As $a+b+c=0$ we can find a pair such that they have the same sign hence WLOG $ab\ge 0$. Now from your attempt we have to prove  $$\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{(a+2)^2}{a^2+8}+\dfrac{(b+2)^2}{b^2+8}+\dfrac{(c+2)^2}{c^2+8} \geq \dfrac{3}{2}$$
by C-S $$\dfrac{(a+2)^2}{a^2+8}+\dfrac{(b+2)^2}{b^2+8}\ge \frac{{(a+b+4)}^2}{a^2+b^2+16}=\frac{{(4-c)}^2}{a^2+b^2+16}\ge \frac{{(4-c)}^2}{c^2+16} $$ here we used $a^2+b^2\le {(a+b)}^2=c^2\iff 2ab\ge 0$

it remains to prove $$\frac{{(4-c)}^2}{c^2+16}+\frac{{(c+2)}^2}{c^2+8}\ge \frac{3}{2}$$ $$\iff \frac{c^2{(c-4)}^2}{2(c^2+16)(c^2+8)}\ge 0$$ which is true

Equality when $a=b=c=0$,

$c=4,a=-2,b=-2$(upto permutations)

Comment: Thank you so much.
Poor me, I forgot we can suppose $ab \geq 0$

Comment: @Nguyenthuyhangaz you are welcome credits to you for making the nice observation

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore for competition solutions, it is often important (sometimes implicit) to state all equality cases. For this, we also have $ c = 4, a = b = - 2$ (and permutations), which you can retrace from the last step. That also explains why the naive approaches don't work well for this question.

Comment: @CalvinLin agreed ,thanks  for pointing it out,i have never written a contest other than the small quizzes in my school and MCQ based contests ,my ignorance in this field is indeed noticble,Is there anyting else i have to add to make it contest like?Thanks for your time

Comment: Most of your solutions (and you know I've seen several of them) are pretty complete. If there was something to point out, I would have already done so.

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks ,also Do you think there is any chance of using Tangent line method with some modifications ,it is very tempting:)

Comment: It most likely wouldn't, because of the equality cases. (Of course, we can't guarantee that an approach will never work. )
To elaborate, with $f(x) = (x+2)^2 / (x^2+8)$, notice that $ x = -2, 4 $ are also turning points. So, if we wanted to do a $ f(x) \geq g(x)$ with equality at $ x = -2, 0, 4$ and $g'(-2) = 0 = g'(4)$, then A) a linear function wouldn't work which making finding $g(a) + g(b) + g(c)$ difficult, B) any other function would likely be more complicated than $f(x)$, and thus likely won't help.